# Slide down a set of hidden <li> s one at a time

Tags: jquery, slidedown

I would like to slide down some li's one at a time on clicking a button .

I mocked up a little fiddle with what I currently have http://jsfiddle.net/S5T7N/ .

```
 <div id="dropdown">


    <h1>when you click here</h1>

    <ul>
    <li>We</li>
    <li>Will</li>
    <li>Slide Down</li>
    <li>One At A Time</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S5T7N/4/).

```
$("#dropdown h1").click( function() {
    var lis = $(this).next('ul').find('li');

    $(lis).each(function(index) {
        var li = $(this);

        setTimeout(function() {
            li.slideDown(500);
        }, 500 * index);
    });
} )
```

This loops through each `li` and sets a timeout that waits for a different time for each `li`. It's currently set to 500ms, as that's the time of the animation. These values should stay the same to get a continuous looking animation.

Comment: Yes it would; just set the timeout time to be less than 500ms. For example, setting it to 250 would make the next `li` slide down half way through the previous `li`'s animation. Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/26PMH/1/) (100ms).

Answer (score 9):

The [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) function has a second argument, which is a callback function to execute when the animation finishes.  Just use that function to slide the next one:

```
var slide = function(who)
{
    who.slideDown('slow', function(){
       var next = $(this).next('li');
       if (next)
           slide(next);
    });
}

$("#dropdown h1").click( function() {
    slide($('li:first'));
})
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/S5T7N/6/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dropdown h1").click( function() {
    var sliderTimer=300;
    $("li").each(function()
                 {
                  $(this).slideDown(sliderTimer);
                     sliderTimer+=300;
                 });
} );
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S5T7N/28/)**